# Printing JSDuck Documentation

Tags: printing, jsduck

I've generated documentation with JsDuck. One thing I noticed was that there was no print button for the guides though I saw it in the online docs?

How do I enable it in the config file when building the doc?
If not available, how should I format the url so as to get the printable version?

An example of the printable version is as at

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/?print=/api/Ext.ComponentQuery#

Tried `http://localhost:50005/?print=/api/SLMS.db.Functions` which simply loaded the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--seo` option. This will enable the print pages which are also used to serve content for search engines (therefore the name "seo"). It's a bit cryptically named option though...

Comment: Thanks. The output php file gave me the understanding I needed to create a docx and pdf version of the html guide. Just a few tweaking left to be done.